# Variance of [-X]

Tags: probability

In the case of two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, being 'most correlated', either $Y=-X$ or $X=Y$.

In the case of $X=Y$, this reduces to 1.

In the case of $Y=-X$, this should reduce to -1

However, I'm having difficulty with this:

the $Var[-X]$ gives an awkward sum such as $Var[X]= -E[X^2]-E[X]^2$?

What am I doing wrong here, given that $Cov(X,-X)$ nicely reduces to $-Var[X]$?

Comment: $\text{Var}(-X) = E((-X)^2) - (E(-X))^2 = E(X^2)-(-E(X))^2 = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = \text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: ok,but if you write the integral, you get something like -integral of x^2 fx dx = -E[X^2]

Comment: Yeah, but why do you say that? @Edward

Comment: "if you write the integral, you get something like -integral of x^2 fx dx = -E[X^2]" No you do not.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
$$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E[X])^2]. $$
Since $$\mathbb E[-X]=-\mathbb E[X],$$
it is evident that
$$\operatorname{Var}(-X)=\operatorname{Var}(X). $$
In general, if $a\in\mathbb R$ then $$\operatorname{Var}(aX)=a^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$$
(this follows from a direct computation).